# Securing paths in PHP

Tags: php, security

I'm writing some PHP which takes some paths to different content directories, and uses these to include various parts of pages later. I'm trying to ensure that the paths are as they seem, and none of them break the rules of the application. Which are,

1. `PRIVATEDIR` (defined relative to `DOCUMENT_ROOT`) must be above `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.
2. `CONTENTDIR` (defined relative to `PRIVATEDIR`) must lie below `PRIVATEDIR` and must not go back in to `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.
3. The remaining `*DIRS`'s (defined relative to `CONTENTDIR`) must lie below `CONTENTDIR`

I'm setting some defaults in a singleton controller class, and then the user passes in an array of the paths they want to override to this classes constructor. I then want to sanity check them to ensure they abide by the above rules. Heres how I've started to go about it...

**EDIT:** *Please note my use of `error_reporting` in the code below, and then don't do it yourself! I misunderstood how that command works. If you're wondering why, see stealthyninja's and Col. Shrapnel's remarks in the comments (and thanks to them for pointing this out to me).*

```
private $opts = array( // defaults
   'PRIVATEDIR'   => '..',        // relative to document root
   'CONTENTDIR'   => 'content',   // relative to private dir
   ...
   ...
);

private function __construct($options) { //$options is the user defined options
    error_reporting(0);
    if(is_array($options)) {
        $this->opts = array_merge($this->opts, $options);
    }

    if($this->opts['STATUS']==='debug') {
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);
    }

    $this->opts['PUBLICDIR']  = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
                                        .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->opts['PRIVATEDIR'] = realpath($this->opts['PUBLICDIR']
                                        .$this->opts['PRIVATEDIR'])
                                        .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->opts['CONTENTDIR'] = realpath($this->opts['PRIVATEDIR']
                                        .$this->opts['CONTENTDIR'])
                                        .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->opts['CACHEDIR']   = realpath($this->opts['CONTENTDIR']
                                        .$this->opts['CACHEDIR'])
                                        .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->opts['ERRORDIR']   = realpath($this->opts['CONTENTDIR']
                                        .$this->opts['ERRORDIR'])
                                        .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->opts['TEMPLATEDIR' = realpath($this->opts['CONTENTDIR']
                                        .$this->opts['TEMPLATEDIR'])
                                        .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

   ...
   ...
   ...


    // then here I have to check that PRIVATEDIR is above PUBLICDIR
    // and that all the rest remain within private dir and don't drop 
    // down into (or below) PUBLICDIR again. And die with an error if
    // they don't conform.
}
```

The thing is this seems like a lot of work to do, especially as it must be run, every time a page is accessed, before I can do anything else (e.g check for a cached version of the page I'm serving), when the paths are essentially static.

Part of me is thinking that the maintainer (currently me) of the site should be aware of what paths they are supplying and should check themselves that they conform to the rules. But the (I think) more sensible side of me is saying, no, I should be equally responsible for checking that the paths conform, since accidents do happen (especially as the site grows/changes/gets a new maintainer...) and if they can be caught, in a security-critical environment, there is no excuse not to catch them.

So, I'm pretty much decided that I DO want to check these paths, the question is how good is my method? It feels like a suboptimal solution. How would you improve it or what alternatives would you suggest? Is there anyway of getting round the problem of having to do it every time a page loads, and somehow just do it when the configuration changes? (That would be ideal, but I don't imagine trivial).

Thanks.

Comment: your error reporting is ridiculous. make it `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` and leave it alone forever

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel. Thanks, but may I ask why? "Everything" I've read has said error reporting should be off when I release. Yes, Ive got it turned off in `php.ini` but I thought the extra level of protection (against accidental deletion (or something) of php.ini) would be a good thing.

Comment: Either you have read articles written by idiots or misunderstood them. it's **display_errors** setting which you should turn off on the production server. Along with log_errors turned on. While error_reporting should be always at max and remain intact. I am also curious, do you have any die() directives in your code?

Comment: @stealthyninja, @Col. Shrapnel. Ah I didn't realise I was turning off error reports to the logs. That I *did not* want or mean to do. Thank-you for pointing it out. I think it may be a mixture of some idiots and some my misunderstanding (or is that just *me* being an idiot?). I know I've read code turning `error_reporting` off as I have done. But it clearly does not do what I thought it did.

Comment: I wonder, what's the etiquette now, should I change the code in my post; I don't want people coming by just seeing the code (not reading these comments) and inadvertently spreading the disease. That said, if I change it, these comments aren't going to make much sense.

Comment: @tjm: I'd say leave the initial code as-is and put __update__ below it all with new/updated code and findings.

Comment: Note that `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT)` is the same as `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` since `E_ALL` already includes everything except `E_STRICT`. (See [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php))

Comment: @Tgr, Thanks for that. A good point. (I don't know if you caught my - now deleted - previous comment to that, but if you did, I apologise, I was clearly having a bit of a brain malfunction).

Answer (score 1):

How about using strpos to find a substring? It's not the most elegant solution, but if you just want some basic protection for someone who already is given a lot of power on the site. Here is how I would do it:

```
// PRIVATEDIR already includes PUBLICDIR at this point
if(strpos($this->opts['PRIVATEDIR'],$this->opts['PUBLICDIR']) !== 0) {
die('ERROR: '.$this->opts['PRIVATEDIR'].' must be located in .'$this->opts['PUBLICDIR']);
}
```

Note the triple not equals, that makes sure that PUBLICDIR occurs at position 0 of the PRIVATEDIR string and not it simply being not found or somewhere else in the string. Also you should check that they aren't the same (PUBLICDIR != PRIVATEDIR) since you could set it to "./test/../" and that would return you to just ".".

Comment: Thanks. I'd have to do all the `realpath` stuff first though right? Cause when the paths are supplied they are relative to each other.

Comment: Exactly, once they go through the realpath function they should be full canonical paths - before realpath, they're dangerously useless! Once they are both in their full path form, you can compare them and make sure that the publicdir substring is the first thing that privatedir contains.

Answer (score 1):

I would just leave it to the site admin to decide where the directories should be, and provide the above as convenient defaults. One might want to use a common error or temp directory for all sites on the server, or put the private dir inside the public one and defend it via .htaccess (bad practice, but might be necessary on some cheap webhosts).

Also, what is the point of array_merging in the constructor? If the `$opts` array cannot get a value before that point, then it is confusing to one reading the code and an error when `E_STRICT` is enabled; if it has a default value or something, then changing it like the way you do is misleading (if someone sees `$opts = array('TEMPLATEDIR'=>'/templates')` in your class definition and then finds a reference to `$config->$opts['TEMPLATEDIR']` somewhere in the code, he will expect it to be `/templates`); you should either use full paths in the options in the first place, or hold the full paths in a different variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but the $opts array *is* populated beforehand when I declare it as `private $opts = array( ... );`, these are the default settings, then in the constructor I'm merging the array with the user defined settings. It's these that I want to (or am wondering whether I should) check for security purposes. I think I need to update/rephrase the question as maybe I have not been to clear. Sorry if that's the case.

Comment: You're right of course, about the confusion that could occur over my changing the paths from relative to absolute in the same array. I'd thought about that but not dwelled on it. I think I will probably take your advice on that one. Good point also about perhaps using a common error directory for the server .. hmm, will think about that. As for putting the private dir inside the public one, I'd also initially allowed for that possibility and just put some hefty comments in the code warning to make sure it's blocked via .htaccess but in the end I decided not to support it at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to ensure that the code stays in the right directories to look for files, why do you use realpath() without checking that your still within the constrained directory? Or are you not concerned about any of these paths containing '../'?

I would infer that at least CACHEDIR is writeable - but is within the document root - this is not a good idea from a security viewpoint.

Also, you are re-writing existing variables, rather than constructing new variables from template values - even though you're doing this in the constructor, this is a rather messy approach for values which really should be final as soon as they are declared.

Comment: Thanks symcbean for your answer, that's exactly what I'm worried about; paths containing `..` or `PRIVATEDIR` being `..` and then `CONTENTDIR` being `public_html` (or equivalent) taking it back into a public area when it shouldn't (and the same with any of the others "breaking out"). I will do that checking where I have put the comment `// then here I have to check ...` in the example, I just didn't type all the checking code in as to not make the example too long. Sorry if that confused matters. And there's the point, all the `realpath`ing and the checking code, seems a lot to have to test ..

Comment: .. every time a page is loaded, when these paths are, for all intents and purposes, static. As for re-writing existing variables, I'm only overwriting the defaults internally set in my class (`$this->opts`), not the array that's passed in. Is this still bad practice?

Comment: Sorry I just reread your post, and I think got confused initially about what you were saying about overwriting the array. I think you're referring to the same problem that Tgr mentions in his answer. In which case, you're absolutely right, and I'm sorry for being a bit slow on the uptake.